# How to read content from a file and store it in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to read the contents from a text file and store them in an 2D array, however I have run into an error.

These are the contents of the file:

## R1  R2  R3  R4  R5

1   J   S2  Q   S2  J
2   J   S2  Q   S2  J
3   J   S2  Q   S2  J
4   J   S2  Q   S2  J
5   J   Q   S5  Q   J
6   S3  Q   S5  Q   S3
7   S3  Q   S5  Q   S3
8   S3  Q   S5  Q   S3
9   S3  S1  S5  S1  S3
10  A   S1  S5  S1  A
11  A   S1  K   S1  A
12  A   S1  K   S1  A
13  A   S1  K   S1  A
14  A   S1  K   S1  A
15  S2  A   K   A   S2
16  S2  A   S3  A   S2
17  S2  A   S3  A   S2
18  S2  A   S3  A   S2
19  S2  A   S3  A   S2
20  Q   S5  S3  S5  Q
21  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
22  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
23  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
24  Q   S5  J   S5  Q
25  S4  K   S2  K   S4
26  S4  K   S2  K   S4
27  S4  K   S2  K   S4
28  S4  K   S2  K   S4
29  S4  K   S2  K   S4
30  K   S4  S2  S4  K
31  K   S4  A   S4  K
32  K   S4  A   S4  K
33  K   S4  A   S4  K
34  K   S4  A   S4  K
35  S1  S4  A   S4  S1
36  S1  A   S1  A   S1
37  S1  A   S1  A   S1
38  S1  A   S1  A   S1
39  S1  A   S1  A   S1
40  Q   S3  S1  S3  Q
41  Q   S3  Q   S3  Q
42  Q   S3  Q   S3  Q
43  Q   S3  Q   S3  Q
44  Q   J   Q   J   Q
45  S2  J   S4  J   S2
46  S2  J   S4  J   S2
47  S2  J   S4  J   S2
48  S2  S2  S4  S2  S2
49  S2  S2  A   S2  S2
50  J   S2  A   S2  J
51  J   S2  A   S2  J
52  J   Q   A   Q   J
53  J   Q   A   Q   J
54  J   Q   J   Q   J
55  S5  Q   J   Q   S5
56  S5  J   J   J   S5
57  S5  J   J   J   S5
58  S5  J   S1  J   S5
59  S5  J   S1  J   S5
60  A   S3  S1  S3  A
61  A   S3  S1  S3  A
62  A   S3  Q   S3  A
63  A   S3  Q   S3  A
64  A   K   Q   K   A
65  S1  K   Q   K   S1
66  S1  K   S4  K   S1
67  S1  K   S4  K   S1
68  S1  Q   S4  Q   S1
69  S1  Q   S4  Q   S1
70  K   Q   K   Q   K
71  K   Q   K   Q   K
72  K   J   K   J   K
73  K   J   K   J   K
74  K   J   K   J   K
75  S3  J   J   J   S3
76  S3  NA  J   NA  S3
77  S3  NA  J   NA  S3
78  S3  NA  J   NA  S3

I have tried to do it by splitting each line into a string array, however I have run into the previous error.
This is my current code:

```
package slots;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Slots {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reels_template.txt")));

   String [][] arr = new String[78][6];

   while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
     for (int i=0; i<78; i++) {
         String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = line[j];
        }
     }
  }

   for (int i = 0; i < 78; i++) {
       for ( int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
           System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }

}
```

}

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at slots.Slots.main(Slots.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

EDIT:

After making some changes based on Logan Wlv's remark, I have ran into the following problem. The code is able to read the file successfully, however it does not read the last element of each line. Updated code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reels_template.txt")));

   String [][] arr = new String[78][6];
   String[] line = {};


     for (int i=0; i<78; i++) {
         if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         line = sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
         }
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {        
            arr[i][j] = line[j] + " ";                             
        }
     }
```

Sample output:

```
# R1 R2 R3 R4 null
1 J S2 Q S2 null
2 J S2 Q S2 null
3 J S2 Q S2 null
```

Comment: It seems your logic is wrong. In the `while` you check if there is an existing line, then you iterate 78 times with `sc.nextLine()`. For me it means you check only the first line exists, but not the 77 other lines..

Comment: Yes, you are correct I have made some changes to the code and am now facing a new problem.

Comment: @VaskoVasilev for (int j=0; j<5; j++) - make j<=5

Comment: Yes... such a stupid mistake. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check for `sc.hasNextLine()` is at wrong place, try following way. Also remove while loop.

```
    for (int i=0; i<78; i++) {
        if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = line[j];
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every-time you have to skip 6 words from the current cursor

```java
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] words = line.trim().split(" ");
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 78; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    arr[i][j] = words[i + j + k];

                }
                k += 5;
            }
        }
```